# Calculating compounded multiple interest for partial years, interest(a) + interest(b) != interest(a+b) for same principal

Tags: microsoft-excel, finance

**Context**

I created a compound interest worksheet that calculates the interest fees, penalties, and total payment due on a contract if it is X days late.

**Goals**

- Enable contract managers to quickly compute the total amount due and inform suppliers of the interest and penalties if they are late.
- Enable flexibility by dynamically selecting annual, monthly, and daily compounding (which can vary by contract and supplier).
- Provide a breakdown of the contract interest, penalty interest, and principal.

**Inputs**

- C3: Past due date
- C4: Focal date (the ending date to compute the
  total days late)
- C8: Stated annualized interest rate
- C9: Penalty rate that is added to the interest rate if the payment is past due
- C10: Period compounding (list dropdown of annual, monthly, or daily), sets D10 to 1, 12, or 365 and reused in main future value function.
- C16: Principal amount due

**("Future Value") Formula**

```
amount_due = contract_principal * (1 + (periodic_rate / num_periods))^((num_periods) * (years))
```

e.g.

```
=C16*(1+C12)^(D10*(D5))-C16
```

- *years* is calculated by taking the days late and dividing by 365.
- *num_periods* depends on whether the user selects Annually, Monthly, and Daily in the dropdown

**Issue**

As a check, I summed up the principal, contract interest, and penalty interest separately, and compare those with the same function but with a summed (contract + penalty) interest in the end, but they always seem to be slightly off.

Said differently: interest(1.50%) + interest (5.00%) != interest(6.50%) on the same principal.

**Example**

The contract (principal) is $10000, the annualized interest rate is 1.50% and the penalty rate is 5.00% on top if they are late beyond 30 days. Combined, that sums to 6.50%. Compounding is monthly. The contract is 426 days late, or 1.167 years.

- interest(1.50%) = $176.50
- interest(5.00%) = $599.54

Yet, interest (1.50% + 5.00%) = $765.68, $13.46 *less* than $776.14 which is the sum of the above two. Where is the difference coming from?

**Inputs and Formulae**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UI7KZ.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0.54% compound interest applied twelve times doesn’t come to 6.5% — you can’t just divide 6.5 by 12. It’s compound, so it comes to 6.7%. The formula you need is `1 - 10 ^ (log(1.065) / 12)`, which is 0.526%.

Comment: Thank you for the the reply. The issue I'm seeing is that interest(a) + interest(b) does not sum up to interest(a+b) on the same principal. Should they be the same, mathematically?

I cleaned up the original example to make more clear.

Comment: @Wibble My answer is your problem. The first of the two numbers that don’t agree is calculated by dividing annual interest rates by 12, which doesn’t work to give you a monthly interest rate. It makes the calculated interest payment too big.